# string cannot start a parameter declaration

Tags: c++, string

I am getting the following compilation errors:

```
bool isRotated(string str1, string str2)  
{

}
```

> 'string' cannot start a parameter declaration

> ) expected

Header files included are:

```
iostream.h
string.h
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This could be caused by number of things. If your code is short, please post it, not just the function

Comment: `std::string` ?

Comment: iostream.h? Are you learning C++ from a 20 year old book?

Comment: I am using TurboC++, I used include<iostream> and did not work, so used iostream.h

Comment: You aren't going to learn very well with ancient tools and references. Start with a more current compiler and maybe [one of these books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @S.Kartik if you use and ask about turbo c++, you should use the tag [[turboc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turboc%2b%2b)]. If you tag just [c++], people will assume that you're using and asking about standard c++.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `iostream.h` nor `string.h` exist in C++*, and the type is called `std::string`.

You seem to be learning from an extremely old resource (outdating what we actually call C++ since 1998).

```
#include <string>

bool isRotated(std::string str1, std::string str2)
{
}
```

<sub><sup>*</sup> Pedants will note that `string.h` is included for compatibility with C, but is better known as `cstring` and is regardless not at all the same header that you are intending to use here.</sub>

Comment: I had learned C++ long time back and just now started brushing up, writing small code...Thanks

Comment: @S.Kartik: Best pick up [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) because you've missed, like, a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I will. Thank you for your inputs, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

There is no fully qualified type name `string` in C++ standard library. All standard library types are declared in the `std` namespace, so the name of the type that you're looking for is `std::string`. Also, you did not include the header which declares `std::string`: `<string>` (`<string.h>` is a completely different header, part of the C standard library which is included in C++ standard library).

P.S. `<iostream.h>` header is not standard - although it was used by some compilers prior to standardization. You're looking for `<iostream>`. Although, your example doesn't use anything from that header.